# Troubleshooting tips for SSH issue on proprietary software

Tags: python, ruby, ssh, operating-system, command-line-interface

I am having an issue establishing a channel with a piece of hardware that we purchased. I can SSH into the VXworks OS using both Putty (on Windows) and the Ubuntu's CLI, however, when I send commands to the hardware using Ruby or Python, I receive "connection closed by remote host."

I did the following:

1. Tried different programming languages with different implementations on different operating systems
2. Tried different versions of Ruby and Net::SSH including the 4.0 alpha
3. Allowed port 22 access to the hardware, on the hardware
4. Adding a timeout
5. Specifying specific Kex keys
6. Narrowing the KEXIT (I believe it is called)
7. Contacted the engineers. They don't believe it is on their end, however they are raising it up the chain
8. Python script inside secureCRT, which actually worked.
9. Using a shell channel instead of exec, which also works interactively.
   What are the next things I should check? I am out of ideas.

---

One engineer said:

> "The scripts do need to have buffering between the commands. I've used securecrt for a scripting."

Here is the secureCRT script that allowed me to connect to the unit. I'm not entirely confident that this is relevant:

```
host = "x.x.x.x"
user = "admin"

def main():
    # Prompt for a password instead of embedding it in a script...
    #
    passwd = crt.Dialog.Prompt("Enter password for " + host, "Login", "", True)

    # Build a command-line string to pass to the Connect method.
    cmd = "/SSH2 /L %s /PASSWORD %s /C 3DES /M MD5 %s" % (user, passwd, host)
    crt.Session.Connect(cmd)


main()
```

Here is the log from the VXworks system:

```
logged out from slot 1
    [82]: JAN 23 05:13:17: alert  : 1/1/1028: clitask1: User admin@x.x.x.x logged in on slot 1
    [83]: JAN 23 05:17:41: debug  : 1/1/1038: sshs: tSshServer: accept socket active.
    [84]: JAN 23 05:17:41: debug  : 1/1/1038: sshs: tSshServer: session index = 0 remote IP x.x.x.x.
    [85]: JAN 23 05:17:41: debug  : 1/1/1038: sshs: connInstance = 4218
    [86]: JAN 23 05:17:42: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: AuthPassword Callback: conn: 4218: user = admin
    [87]: JAN 23 05:17:42: alert  : 1/1/1078: clitask0: User admin@x.x.x.x logged in on slot 1
    [88]: JAN 23 05:17:42: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: RxCallback: session: 0 event: OPEN
    [89]: JAN 23 05:17:42: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: SshInTask: after while() loop, status = -6911, cleanUp = 0
    [90]: JAN 23 05:17:42: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: _SshExit(0, 0) called
    [91]: JAN 23 05:19:43: debug  : 1/1/1038: sshs: tSshServer: accept socket active.
    [92]: JAN 23 05:19:43: debug  : 1/1/1038: sshs: tSshServer: session index = 0 remote IP x.x.x.x.
    [93]: JAN 23 05:19:43: debug  : 1/1/1038: sshs: connInstance = 4219
    [94]: JAN 23 05:19:46: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: AuthPassword Callback: conn: 4219: user = admin
    [95]: JAN 23 05:19:46: alert  : 1/1/1078: clitask0: User admin@x.x.x.x logged in on slot 1
    [96]: JAN 23 05:19:46: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: RxCallback: session: 0 event: OPEN
    [97]: JAN 23 05:19:46: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: SshInTask: after while() loop, status = -6911, cleanUp = 0
    [98]: JAN 23 05:19:46: debug  : 1/1/1078: sshs: _SshExit(0, 0) called
    [99]: JAN 23 05:21:55: alert  : 1/1/1028: clitask1: User admin@x.x.x.x logged out from slot 1
    [100]: JAN 23 05:23:29: alert  : 1/1/1028: clitask1: User admin@x.x.x.x logged in on slot 1
```

Here is the log from Net::SSH

```
[2016-05-02T13:41:48.064959 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[11a9720]: establishing connection to 10.100.0.31:22
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.066315 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[11a9720]: connection established
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.066422 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[11a8eec]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.066440 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[11a8eec]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_4.0.0.alpha3 x86_64-linux'
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.069158 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[11a8eec]: remote is `SSH-2.0-Mocana SSH'
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070131 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 424 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070230 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 420
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070288 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[11a85f0]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070350 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[11a85f0]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070450 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1156
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070574 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 1160 bytes
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070615 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[11a85f0]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070694 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[11a85f0]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
* host_key: ssh-dss
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.070740 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[11a85f0]: exchanging keys
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.071565 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 1 type 30 len 140
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.071659 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 144 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.276487 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 448 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.276613 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 444
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.277173 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 2 type 21 len 20
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.277280 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.280778 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 16 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.280829 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: received packet nr 2 type 21 len 12
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.281017 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[11d6f40]: beginning authentication of `admin'
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.281089 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 3 type 5 len 28
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.281231 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.282232 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 52 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.282290 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: received packet nr 3 type 6 len 28
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.282386 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[11d6f40]: trying none
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.282458 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 4 type 50 len 44
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.282537 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.284239 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 52 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.284306 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: received packet nr 4 type 51 len 28
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.284352 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[11d6f40]: allowed methods: password
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.284387 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[11dfcf8]: none failed
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.284420 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[11d6f40]: trying password
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.284489 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 60
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.284569 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 84 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.295419 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 36 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.295559 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: received packet nr 5 type 52 len 12
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.295638 #89562] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.password[11de8a8]: password succeeded
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.295769 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 6 type 90 len 44
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.295911 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297023 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 52 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297124 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: received packet nr 6 type 91 len 28
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297203 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[11e3f88]: channel_open_confirmation: 0 85460946 1000 1000
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297353 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[11e3df8]: sending channel request "env"
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297444 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 7 type 98 len 44
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297579 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[11e3df8]: sending channel request "exec"
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297637 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: queueing packet nr 8 type 98 len 28
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:48.297871 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: sent 120 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:49.297172 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 140 bytes
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:49.297469 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 0 bytes
I, [2016-05-02T13:41:49.297762 #89562]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[11e3f88]: closing remaining channels (1 open)
D, [2016-05-02T13:41:49.297895 #89562] DEBUG -- socket[11a934c]: read 0 bytes
Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Consider asking this on [su], as they're more about overall system problems and communication between systems. Talking to devices via SSH can be a nightmare; SSH versions differ, especially when using a language to talk to a device vs. doing it from the command-line.

Comment: My guess is that the device doesn't support ssh "exec" channels. Interactive sessions use a "shell" channel, and that may be the only thing supported by the device. Try opening a shell channel and writing the command into that.